# Connecting to a Server via Windows Remotedesktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I am trying to get access to a server where I was given the IPv4 and IPv6 aswell as the root-userdata. Now I started the remote desktop and should insert the remote computername and a username. When I insert the IP he tries to initialize the remoteconnection. Then he does not ask me for authentication (like I expected) but says that he could not connect to the remotecomputer for one of the following reasons:

1. Remote is not activated
2. Remotecomputer is turned off
3. Remotecomputer is not accessible in this network

I am working on a coorporate device. Since I am quite sure, that the server is turned on and the remote is active, I thought if I need to add something to connect to that server.

The provider told me that the server can be accessed via SSH2.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Hi, We need more specific information to be able to assist you in this matter. You talk about remote desktop, and end with SSH2, which are two different methods of connecting. Please clarify your question with more information on the nature of the server you are connecting to (Operating system, version, LAN or WAN etc), the machine you are connecting from (Operating system, version etc), and what information you have been given for the connection.

Comment: SSH2 is not remote desktop. SSH2 is a  CLI connection, not a connection to a graphical shell. You could try connecting using an SSH client like putty.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, **RemoteDesktop is not SSH**.

RemoteDesktop is typically used to connect to Windows computers.
SSH is typically used to connect to Linux computers.

The biggest difference is that RemoteDesktop is graphical, SSH is command line.

You were told the server can be access via SSH. So, you will need to download an SSH client to do that. [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) is one of the most common.